# Use System Tray Space for Application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to more space for my game application. If I will use the system tray space for application, Microsoft requires any setting for system tray for user otherwise any problem happend for microsfot certification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no certification requirements around the system tray's visibility, as far as I am aware.  The APIs provide the means to hide the tray as follows...

**Silverlight**

In the page declaration for any page you want to hide the system tray, add the following.

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

**XNA**

In the constructor for the pages where you want to hide the system tray, find the line

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
```

and after it, add the following

```
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```